# How to display a parent node with all the children in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, nodes

I am having trouble with adding all of my sprite nodes to a single parent node and then displaying all of the children inside of that parent node on the screen.

My current and working method is simply taking the children that were added to the sprites' methods and calling it within the `- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size` method.

So it current looks and works like this:

**Code within the MenuScene.m:**

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size]){

        _skyColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:25.0/255.0 green:171.0/225 blue:1 alpha:1];

        [self setBackgroundColor:_skyColor];

        [self nameMovement];
        [self playButtonPushed];
        [self groundMovement];
        [self cloudMovement];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The following code works well, but I would rather only having one node holding all of the children that are held by the groundMovement, cloudMovement..etc methods.

I have tried making a new SKNode called _moving, and then doing this to the rest of the methods that hold sprites with movement.

Below is the groundMovement method where I have tried to implement the parent node I had created called _moving (the only change I have made is at the bottom). Also when I did this I initialised the SKNode in the new initWithSize by adding `_moving = [SKNode node];`
**new initWithSize with SKNode declared and the parent node attempted to be drawn (The SKNode *_moving is in the .h file):**

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size]){

        _skyColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:25.0/255.0 green:171.0/225 blue:1 alpha:1];

        [self setBackgroundColor:_skyColor];

        SKNode *_moving = [SKNode node];

        [self addChild:_moving];
    }

    return self;
}
```

**groundMovement method:**

```
- (void)groundMovement{
    //Ground texture declaration
    groundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Ground"];
    groundTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    //SKAction Declarations
    groundSpriteMovement = [SKAction moveByX:-groundTexture.size.width/2 y:0 duration:0.04 * 100];
    resetgroundSpriteMovement = [SKAction moveByX:groundTexture.size.width/2 y:0 duration:0];
    repeatForevergroundSpriteMovement = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[groundSpriteMovement, resetgroundSpriteMovement]]];

    //Ground Sprite declaration
    groundSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:groundTexture];
    groundSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    groundSprite.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [groundSprite runAction:repeatForevergroundSpriteMovement];

    [_moving addChild:groundSprite];

}
```

Comment: "I would rather only having one node holding all of the children that are held by the groundMovement, cloudMovement..etc methods". There is a node which holds all the children, and it's the SKScene (self). How is it being rendered currently? Please provide a description of the same.

Comment: @akashg I mean that when I create a SKNode called _moving. I will store all of my sprite nodes such as groundSprite, cloudSprite..etc in the one _moving node. Thus, in the initWithSize method it will only need to draw once instead of the 4 draws it will have to do in my current and working method.

Comment: why do you want to do this? Saving 3 draw calls (if that is your intention) will hardly make a difference in fps (if that is your goal).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D the less lines of code, the simpler and more beautiful the code looks :3